# Not a string or buffer. Module Crypto

Tags: node.js, node-crypto

I created on the module `util.js` a function `myHash()` for reuse in different parts of my code but not working.

**Error message:** `this._binding.update(data, encoding); Not a string or buffer.`

**app.js**

```
...
GLOBAL.util = require('./util');
GLOBAL.dateFormat = util.dateFormat;
GLOBAL.myHash = util.myHash; /***** My function *****/
...

app.post('/test', function(req, res){
    ...
    var pass_shasum = myHash('test');
...
```

**util.js**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
function myHash(msg) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(msg).digest('hex');
}

exports.util = {
    ...
    myHash: myHash(),
    ...
};
```

Any suggestions?

---

### **Solution:**

Modify **util.js**

```
var crypto = require('crypto');

/* Define var */
var myHash = function (msg) {
    return crypto.createHash('sha256').update(msg).digest('hex');
};

module.exports = {
    ...
    myHash: myHash, /* Is a variable not a method. Thanks @robertklep */
    ...
};
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Is the traceback actually pointing to the code in `myHash`?

Comment: In the post method 'test', I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't execute the function in your exports statement (the `msg` argument will be `undefined` which indeed is not a string or a buffer):

```
exports.util = {
    ...
    myHash: myHash, // don't use myHash()
    ...
};
```

Also, when you export your code like this, you have to require it like this:

```
GLOBAL.util = require('./util').util;
```

(although I would suggest not using globals).

If you don't want the extra `.util`, export like this:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  myHash : myHash,
  ...
};
```

Comment: Aditionally I declared var myHash in util.js.
I added the solution to my question.
Thanks @robertklep